# DIN webfont in Firefox and IE not working

Tags: css, firefox, fonts, webfonts

I'm having problems with implementing the DIN font in Firefox and MSIE. It works fine in Chrome.

Here's the import code:

```
@font-face {    
font-family: DINweb;
src: url('/wp-content/themes/quickstep-child/DINWeb.eot');
src: url('/wp-content/themes/quickstep-child/DINWeb.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('/wp-content/themes/quickstep-child/DINWeb.woff') format('woff'),
url('/wp-content/themes/quickstep-child/DINWeb.ttf') format('truetype'); 
font-weight: normal; 
font-style: normal;
}
```

The font is being called like this in CSS:

```
font-family:  DINWeb, sans-serif!important;
```

The website is [www.andvordgrafisk.no](http://www.andvordgrafisk.no)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax is working for me:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DIN_Medium'; 
    src: url('../fonts/DIN_Medium.eot'); /* IE9 Compatibility Modes */
    src: url('../fonts/DIN_Medium.eot?') format('eot'),  /* IE6-IE8 */
    url('../fonts/DIN_Medium.otf') format('otf'), 
    url('../fonts/DIN_Medium.ttf') format('truetype'); /* Safari, Android, iOS */
    }
```

If you don't have the extension, you can generate them here http://www.freefontconverter.com/

Answer (score 1):

The Firefox console shows error messages that say, both for the .woff resource and the .ttf resource, “downloadable font: download failed [...] bad URI or cross-site access not allowed”. The Firebug console says: “NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.andvordgrafisk.no/wp-content/themes/quickstep-child/DINWeb.ttf”, but only for the .ttf file.

Oddly enough, it seems that if you remove `url('/wp-content/themes/quickstep-child/DINWeb.ttf') format('truetype')`, Firefox starts using the font. So it’s as if the nonexistent .ttf is the problem, even though Firefox should not even fetch it (as the .woff resource is mentioned first).